calculate df available space
I made a partition of 5 GB -> /dev/sdd2
then made a filesystem sudo mke2fs -N 700 -t ext4 -L test2 /dev/sdd2
and set root reserved space to 0 sudo tune2fs -r 0 /dev/sdd2
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdd2 shows:
Filesystem volume name:   test2
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          64f07e45-910b-4e65-92ba-3ce7fdf1242f
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1216
Block count:              1220864
Reserved block count:     0
Overhead clusters:        21320
Free blocks:              1199538
Free inodes:              1205
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      596
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         32
Inode blocks per group:   2
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sun Jun 16 11:26:49 2024
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Sun Jun 16 11:30:12 2024
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Sun Jun 16 11:26:49 2024
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          2417 kB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      9ce4737d-6beb-437d-a2fe-adaaa6142d11
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x7b46d4d5
Journal features:         (none)
Total journal size:       64M
Total journal blocks:     16384
Max transaction length:   16384
Fast commit length:       0
Journal sequence:         0x00000001
Journal start:            0

df /dev/sdd2 shows:
/dev/sdd2        4798176    24   4781768   1% /media/lithium/test2

4798176−4781768=16408
Where are the 16 MBs ?
How does df calculate the available space - formula?
Why are the inodes 1216, i defined 700?
Can somebode help me?
Special thanx to Marcus Müller.
Is that right?. i tried a partition stat for better knowledge of filesystem, save as dfe, requires sudo because of dumpe2fs infos
Usage e.g.: dfe --help or sudo dfe /dev/sdd2
#!/usr/bin/bash
declare -a df_ARR
declare dumpFS df_output FSvolumeName FSuuid FSfeatures FStype FSosType partition mounted unit=M\
        journalSize inodeTableSize partitionSize overheadISize overheadIISize rootReservedSize usedSize freeSize availableSize GDTreservedSize\
        DP usedPercent useablePercent availablePercent fullReservedPercent\
        C1=$'\e[38;2;0;200;0m' C2=$'\e[38;2;200;200;0m' C3=$'\e[38;2;120;180;220m' C4=$'\e[38;2;220;110;120m'\

declare -i inodeCount inodeSize inodesFree partitionBlocks blockSize freeBlocks usedBlocks journalBlocks rootReservedBlocks GDTreservedBlocks\
           inodeTableBlocks overheadIBlocks overheadIIBlocks df_1kBlocks availableBlocks nUserUseableBlocks\
           max_blockNumber_L max_SizeNumber_L\
           blocksPerGroup inodesPerGroup groupDescriptorSize

DP=$(locale decimal_point)
divide_INTtoFLOAT ()
   {
   local -n LOC_var="$1"; local LOC_c; local -i LOC_a=$2 LOC_b=$3 LOC_d=$4+1 LOC_e=-$4
   (( LOC_c=LOC_a*10**LOC_d/LOC_b))
   LOC_a=${LOC_c: -1}; LOC_c=${LOC_c:0:-1}
   ((LOC_a>4 ? LOC_c++ : 0))
   LOC_b=${#LOC_c}; for ((LOC_a=LOC_d;LOC_a>LOC_b;LOC_a--)); do LOC_c="0$LOC_c"; done
   LOC_var="${LOC_c:0: LOC_e}$DP${LOC_c: LOC_e}"
   }

calculate_SizeInUnits ()
   {
   local -n var=$1; local value unitSTR; local -i i l lN; 
   case $unit in
      "K") value=$2;unitSTR="KB";;
      "M") value=$(($2/1000));unitSTR="MB";;
      "G") value=$(($2/1000**2));unitSTR="GB";;
      "k") value=$(($2*1000/1024));unitSTR="kiB";;
      "m") value=$(($2*1000/1024**2));unitSTR="MiB";;
      "g") value=$(($2*1000/1024**3));unitSTR="GiB";;
   esac

   lN=${value: -1}; value=${value:0:-1}
   if ((lN>4)); then ((value++)); fi
   l=${#value}; for ((i=3;i>l;i--)); do value="0$value"; done
   var="${value:0:-2},${value: -2} $unitSTR"
   }
   
assign_Values ()
   {
   local -n var=$1; local value;
   [[ $dumpFS =~ "$2"[^$'\n']* ]]; value=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}; value=${value#*:}
   var=${value##*( )}
   }
   

if [[ $1 == "--help" ]]; then
echo -e "\e[38;2;123;183;51m\e[1;4mUsage:\e[39m\e[22;24;4:0m dfe [\e[38;2;240;240;0m\e[3mOPTION...\e[39m\e[23m] [\e[38;2;240;240;0m\e[3mDEVICE\e[39m\e[23m]"
echo -e "prints disk usage and partition info!\n"
echo -e "\e[38;2;123;183;51m\e[1;4mDepends On:\e[39m\e[22;24;4:0m commands - df, dumpe2fs\n"
echo -e "\e[38;2;123;183;51m\e[1;4mOptions:\e[39m\e[22;24;4:0m"
echo -e "\t-u \e[38;2;240;240;0m\e[3munit   \e[39m\e[23m    \e[38;2;103;134;250mCHAR\e[39m ... K, M, G for KB, MB, GB - k, m, g for KiB, MiB, GiB - Standard: M"
echo -e "\t-v \e[38;2;240;240;0m\e[3mversion\e[39m\e[23m         ... output version information and exit."
exit
fi

while getopts "u:v" "option"; do
   case $option in
      "u") unit=$OPTARG;;
      "v") echo "df(e)xtended - version: 1.00 - 2024"; exit;;
      "?") exit 2;;
   esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

shopt -s extglob

dumpFS=$(dumpe2fs -h "$1" 2> /dev/null)
if [[ $dumpFS == *"Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock"* ]]; then echo "Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock!" 1>&2; exit 5; fi

assign_Values "FSvolumeName" "volume name" ; assign_Values "FSuuid" "UUID"; assign_Values "FSfeatures" "features"; assign_Values "FSosType" "OS type";
assign_Values "inodeCount" "Inode count"; assign_Values "inodeSize" "Inode size"; assign_Values "inodesFree" "Free inodes"
assign_Values "partitionBlocks" "Block count"; assign_Values "blockSize" "Block size"; assign_Values "freeBlocks" "Free blocks"; #assign_Values "gdtReservedBlocks" "GDT blocks"
assign_Values "journalBlocks" "Total journal blocks"; assign_Values "GDTreservedBlocks" "GDT"
assign_Values "rootReservedBlocks" "Reserved block count"
assign_Values "blocksPerGroup" "Blocks per group"; assign_Values "inodesPerGroup" "Inodes per group"; assign_Values "groupDescriptorSize" "descriptor size"

df_output=$(df -T "$1"); df_output=${df_output#*$'\n'}; df_ARR=($df_output)
partition=${df_ARR[0]}; FStype=${df_ARR[1]}; df_1kBlocks=${df_ARR[2]}; usedBlocks=${df_ARR[3]}; availableBlocks=${df_ARR[4]}; mounted=${df_ARR[6]}

((usedBlocks=usedBlocks/4,\
  availableBlocks=availableBlocks/4,\
  inodeTableBlocks=inodeSize*inodeCount/4096,\
  df_1kBlocks=df_1kBlocks/4,\
  overheadIBlocks=partitionBlocks-(journalBlocks+inodeTableBlocks+df_1kBlocks+GDTreservedBlocks),\
  overheadIIBlocks=df_1kBlocks-(rootReservedBlocks+usedBlocks+availableBlocks),\
  nUserUseableBlocks=availableBlocks+usedBlocks ))

calculate_SizeInUnits "partitionSize"    "$((partitionBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "journalSize"      "$((journalBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "inodeTableSize"   "$((inodeTableBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "GDTreservedSize"  "$((GDTreservedBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "overheadISize"    "$((overheadIBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "overheadIISize"   "$((overheadIIBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "rootReservedSize" "$((rootReservedBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "usedSize"         "$((usedBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "freeSize"         "$((freeBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "availableSize"    "$((availableBlocks*4096))"
calculate_SizeInUnits "nUserUseableSize" "$((nUserUseableBlocks*4096))"

max_blockNumber_L=${#partitionBlocks}; max_SizeNumber_L=${#partitionSize}

echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Partition:";  echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; echo $'\t'"$partition - $FSosType file system $FStype"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Volume Name:";echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; echo $'\t'"$FSvolumeName"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "UUID:     ";  echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; echo $'\t'"$FSuuid"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Features:";   echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; echo $'\t'"$FSfeatures"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Mounted on:"; echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; echo $'\t'"$mounted"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Groups:";     echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; printf "\t%-${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$(((partitionBlocks+blocksPerGroup-1)/blocksPerGroup))"; echo " - Group descriptor size: $groupDescriptorSize bytes - Inodes per group: $inodesPerGroup - Blocks per group: $blocksPerGroup" 
divide_INTtoFLOAT "usedPercent" "$(((inodeCount-inodesFree)*100))" "$inodeCount" "3"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Inodes:";     echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; printf "\t%-${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$inodeCount"; echo " - Free inodes: $inodesFree (used: ${usedPercent}%) - Inode size: $inodeSize bytes - Inode ratio: 1 inode per $(((partitionBlocks+inodeCount-1)/inodeCount)) blocks"
echo -n "$C1" >/dev/tty; echo -n "Blocks:";     echo -n $'\e[39m '>/dev/tty; printf "\t%-${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$partitionBlocks"; echo " - Free blocks: $freeBlocks total - Block size: $blockSize bytes"


echo -n "   Journal             :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$journalBlocks";     echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s\n" "$journalSize"
echo -n "   Inode table        ~:   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$inodeTableBlocks";  echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s\n" "$inodeTableSize"
echo -n "   Other FS overhead 1 :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$overheadIBlocks";   echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s\n" "$overheadISize"
echo -n "   GD table reserved   :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$GDTreservedBlocks"; echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s\n" "$GDTreservedSize"
echo -n "$C3" >/dev/tty
echo -n "   Other FS overhead 2 :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$overheadIIBlocks";  echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s" "$overheadIISize";  echo $' \u2500\e[17b\u252C\u2500 df blocks: '"$df_1kBlocks - $((df_1kBlocks*4)) 1k blocks"
echo -n "   Root reserved       :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$rootReservedBlocks";echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s" "$rootReservedSize";echo $' \e[18b\u2502'

echo -n "$C2" >/dev/tty
echo -n "   Used blocks         :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$usedBlocks";        echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s"   "$usedSize";      echo $' \u2500\u252C\u2500 nUser useable \u2502'
echo -n "   Available blocks    :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$availableBlocks";   echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s"   "$availableSize"; echo $' \u2500\u2534\u2500\e[15b\u2518'
echo -n $'\e[39m' >/dev/tty
echo    "                          "$'\u2500\e['"$((max_blockNumber_L+max_SizeNumber_L+9))b"
divide_INTtoFLOAT "availablePercent" "$((availableBlocks*100))" "$partitionBlocks" "3"
divide_INTtoFLOAT "fullReservedPercent" "$(((partitionBlocks-availableBlocks)*100))" "$partitionBlocks" "3"
echo -n "$C4" >/dev/tty
echo -n "   Partition blocks    :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$partitionBlocks";   echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s\n" "$partitionSize (available: ${availablePercent}% - full & reserved: ${fullReservedPercent}%)"

divide_INTtoFLOAT "useablePercent" "$((nUserUseableBlocks*100))" "$partitionBlocks" "3"
echo -n "$C2" >/dev/tty
echo -n "   nUser useable       :   "; printf "%${max_blockNumber_L}s" "$nUserUseableBlocks";echo -n " blocks   "; printf "%${max_SizeNumber_L}s\n" "$nUserUseableSize (useable: ${useablePercent}%)" 
echo -n $'\e[39m' >/dev/tty


So, the sad part up front: I can't tell you in each detail why the filesystem is structured the way it is – multiple decades of experience, features and bug fixes flow into that, and the ext2/3/4 source tree in the kernel source is not exactly small.
I will still try to address the explicit questions you ask:

Where are the 16 MBs?

File system overhead. I know this sounds silly, but think about how block groups are supposed to be independent enough to reduce contention – some metadata structures will have to be duplicated among these.
Also, superblock backups.

How does df calculate the available space - formula?

not at all. It asks the kernel, via the statvfs function (wrapped in gnulib. Don't read gnulib code if you can avoid it, it's very #ifdef heavy). What these values actually mean is for all practical purposes basically undefined. So, the answer to your question "how is the total size in blocks calculated?" is honestly "you'll have to look this up in the Linux kernel ext4 driver source code".

Why are the inodes 1216, i defined 700?

No, you defined 700 to be reserved. Obviously, reserving more is especially reserving 700; this is compatible with what you wanted!
Probably, it's the smallest sensible size for the 38 block groups you seem to have (divide the number of blocks by the blocks per group, round up). And, 1216 actually happens to be 38 · 32; my guess is that you can't allocate inode tables of arbitrary size, they always need to contain a power of 2, or some other relatively sensible restriction on a file system. You can verify that yourself: specify -n 7000; you should be getting 7296 (= 38 · 192 = 38 · 64 · 3).
To be completely honest, trying to build a file system with 700 inodes seems – wrong. At the very least, you'd have to reduce the number of block groups (I'm not sure how far ext4 will allow you to do that); at that point, why use ext4? Seems like the wrong filesystem to whatever job you're solving here!

thank you!!!!!!!1

i checked all my partitions the 16MB are exactly 16MiB, 4096 blocks on every partition, i wanted to write a tool which creates exact x000000 MB of available space. i see that partition size *0.978 is average available space on all my partitions.

yeah, as you can see, it's not going to be that easy with a fixed factor. And using "esoterically small" inode reservations is not going to make useful filesystems with that much free space. What happens after you allocated the 700th inode? Great, you might still have free space, but can't make new files or even directories.

The other question that I'd have here is "what for?"; you pay for storage by the underlying block, not by the free space you give users of that storage.

lets say i need a disk for storage of 500 movies and i want to give space for that, but not more to dont waste space! Its for calculation and Its also for understanding the filesystem

"don't waste space": How so? You pay for the storage you buy or rent, and that's not available in arbitrarily fine granularity. The only exception I could think of would be thin-provisioned storage (eg an LVM thin volume), but then you don't need at all concern yourself with 10% overprovisioning – you just use the blocks that the file system actually uses, not the nominal size of the block device. Obviously, if you have a "normal" block device that you can divide into volumes, the most space-efficient approach is one file system spanning the whole device, and if needed, subvolumes on that.

I thought myself,  i should partition a big drive,  for smaller inode tables, isnt the file access than faster? what are subvolumes, is that partitions, or folders?

no, it's not faster. Why should it? The data structures in file systems aren't flat lists and looking for files is not going through the whole list at once. Also, again, make a difference between reserved and used inodes.
